# remove stop words from a string in order to create clusters

Tags: java

i need to use openrefine, to get some clusters. It is written in Java.

What i cannot achieve, is how should i alter the code:

https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/blob/master/main/src/com/google/refine/clustering/binning/FingerprintKeyer.java

especially here in the line 93:

https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/blob/c76e2b9a461ed5b353ebf5c80e0e0cad2163331c/main/src/com/google/refine/clustering/binning/FingerprintKeyer.java#L93

```
s = s.trim(); // first off, remove whitespace around the string
s = s.toLowerCase(); // TODO: This is using the default locale. Is that what we want?
s = normalize(s);
s = punctctrl.matcher(s).replaceAll(""); // decomposition can generate punctuation so strip it after
String[] frags = StringUtils.split(s); // split by whitespace (excluding supplementary characters)
TreeSet<String> set = new TreeSet<String>();
for (String ss : frags) {
   set.add(ss); // order fragments and dedupe
}
```

so as to also remove the word "and", the "&" symbol, prior to generate the clusters?

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking, you need to use that library, but you need to change the behavior?

Comment: exactly, i need to alter the code in the line mentioned, so from the tsring under question, to also exclude dome words like "and", "the", "&"

Comment: You can't change the behavior of the lib, in that case you need to implement a new class in your project an use it, or create a fork of the lib and compile yourself (Wich it's note recommend). Somithing like `public class MyOwnFingerprintKeyer extends FingerprintKeyer`  and @Override the method that you want to change

Comment: i plan to change the code and compile myself, the problem is ii have not managed to achieve what i want altering the above code. So if one can give me a working code, i then can compile the source

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the words or characters you want to remove from string into a String[] array and then remove use a loop to carry out the task:

```
String[] alsoReplace = {"and", "the", "&"};
for (String str : alsoReplace) {
    s = s.replaceAll("(?i)" + str + "(\\s+)?" , "");
}
```

Comment: going to add the suggested code before this line: String[] frags = StringUtils.split(s); // split by whitespace (excluding supplementary characters) line 90. at least this is where i have put my attempts to solve this